# @MapsId and two objects with the same identifier value associated with the session

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have `@OneToOne` relationship between my entities `DirigeantsEntreprise`  and `Fournisseur` like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dirigeants_entreprise", catalog = "ao")
public class DirigeantsEntreprise implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int idEntreprise;
    private Fournisseur fournisseur;
    private String nom;
    private String poste;
    ....

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_entreprise", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdEntreprise() {
        return this.idEntreprise;
    }
    ...

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_entreprise")
    public Fournisseur getFournisseur() {
        return this.fournisseur;
    }
```

but when i try to save object :

```
....
fournisseur_respository.save(fournisseur);
dirigeants_repo.save( new DirigeantsEntreprise( fournisseur,...,... ));
```

i got this exception :

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: 
A different object with the same identifier value was already associated   with 
the session : [persistence.DirigeantsEntreprise#35]
```

PS : 35 is the ID of my `fournisseur`

I thinks the problem is with maps and i have two object of `DirigeantsEntreprise` and `Fournisseur` with same identifier `35`.

How to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We Have to flush the session by `saveAndFlush()` so it will be just one object with same identifier.

```
....
fournisseur_respository.saveAndFlush(fournisseur);
dirigeants_repo.save( new DirigeantsEntreprise( fournisseur,...,... ));
```